# Redraw old buffer question

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

My main scene is composed of GL_POINTS in 3D space.  What I would like to do is be able to draw a single GL_LINES line (2d overlay) on top of the scene as the user moves his finger across the screen while retaining the underlaying 3D GL_POINTS state.  I am having trouble understanding if this is possible.  Do I need 2 framebuffers?  How do I save the previous framebuffer data of GL_POINTS and re-render that in subsequent frames?  Do I need to mix framebuffers - one for the GL_LINE layer and one for the GL_POINTS data?

I tried only calling presentFramebuffer without calling setFramebuffer but that is retaining each GL_LINES drawn from previous frames - which I do not want.  How do I retain parts of the framebuffer and remove other parts?

Answer (score 0):

1. you do not need a 2 frame-buffers at all

   - frame buffer is your screen memory
   - just render all stuff on that one you have
2. if you mean by frame-buffer VBO (VertexBufferObject) then they are not the same at all

   - if you render the same data (vertexes)
   - then you need just 1x VBO
   - and call glDrawArrays/glDrawElements twice
   - once with GL_POINTS and once with GL_LINES/GL_LINE_LOOP or whatever
   - if you render different data
   - then you need 2x VBO
   - or if there are only few Lines then you can still use glBegin/glEnd for them instead.
3. if you just need separate areas of view then you can use

   - clipping, change view-port, overwrite borders by quads, ...
   - draw to texture, and so on ... there is a lot of options more there